# Simple test program looping issues

Tags: java, loops, switch-statement

I work at Jimmy John's and I'm working on a test for the sandwiches. I got the basic structure down but when you answer the wrong question it continues on to the next question. I need it to re-ask the question then continue on in the loop. Here is the code:

```
package Practice;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class jimmyTest { 
public static void main (String args[]){
int age, menuItem;

String tomato, lettuce, mayo, ham, turkey, tuna, beef, capicola, salami, cheese, onion, sauce, oregano, avacado, dijon, sprouts;
tomato = ("Tomato");
lettuce = ("lettuce");
mayo = ("mayo");
ham = ("ham");
turkey = ("turkey");
beef = ("beef");
capicola = ("capicola");
salami = ("Salami");
cheese = ("cheese");
onion = ("onion");
sauce = ("sauce");
oregano = ("oregano");
avacado = ("avacado");
dijon = ("dijon");
sprouts = ("sprouts");
tuna = ("tuna");
Scanner item = new Scanner(System.in);  
Scanner item1 = new Scanner(System.in); 
Scanner item2 = new Scanner(System.in); 
Scanner item3= new Scanner(System.in);   
Scanner item4 = new Scanner(System.in); 
Scanner item5 = new Scanner(System.in); 
Scanner item6 = new Scanner(System.in); 
Scanner item7 = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner item9 = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner item10 = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner item11 = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner item12 = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner item13 = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner item14 = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner item15 = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner item16 = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner item17 = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner item18 = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner finished = new Scanner(System.in);
String scan1, scan2, scan3, scan4, scan5, scan6, scan7, scan8, scan9, scan10, scan11, scan12, scan13, scan14, scan15, scan16, scan17, scan18, fin;
/*
 * scan1 = item1.next();    
 * scan2 = item2.next();    
 * scan3 = item3.next();    
 * scan4 = item4.next();    
 * scan5 = item5.next();    
 * scan6 = item6.next();    
 * scan7 = item7.next();    
 * scan8 = item8.next();    
 * scan9 = item9.next();    
 * scan10 = item10.next();  
 * scan11 = item11.next();  
 * scan12 = item12.next();  
 * scan13 = item13.next();  
 * scan14 = item14.next();  
 * scan15 = item15.next();  
 * scan16 = item16.next();  
 * scan17 = item17.next();  
 * scan18 = item18.next();  
 * fin = finished.next();   
 * 
 */
System.out.println("This is a test over the Jimmy Johns menu. a menu Item will appear, enter each");
System.out.println("item that goes into the sandwich and press enter as you type each item.");
menuItem = 0;
int points;
points = 0;
do {
switch (menuItem){
case 0:
    System.out.println("What items are on the Slim 1 from the bread up");
    scan1 = item1.next();   
    scan2 = item2.next();   
    if (scan1.contains(ham) && scan2.contains(cheese)){
        System.out.println("Great job!");
        menuItem =+ 1;
        points++;
        System.out.println(points);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Lets try that again!"); 
    }


    //*****************************
case 1:
    System.out.println("What items are on the Slim 2 from the bread up");
    scan1 = item1.next();   

    if (scan1.contains(beef)){
        System.out.println("Great job!");
        menuItem =+ 1;
        points++;
        System.out.println(points);

    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Lets try that again!"); 
        menuItem = 1;
        points = 1;
        scan1 = item1.next();

    }

    //***********************************8




case 2:
    System.out.println("What items are on the Slim 3 from the bread up");
    scan1 = item1.next();       
    if (scan1.contains(tuna)){
        System.out.println("Great job!");
        menuItem =+ 1;
        points++;
        System.out.println(points);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Lets try that again!"); 
        menuItem = 2;
    }
case 3:
    System.out.println("What items are on the Slim 4 from the bread up");
    scan1 = item1.next();       
    if (scan1.contains(turkey)){
        System.out.println("Great job!");
        menuItem =+ 1;
        points++;
        System.out.println(points);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Lets try that again!"); 
        menuItem = 3;

    }
case 4:
    System.out.println("What items are on the Slim 5 from the bread up");
    scan1 = item1.next();
    scan2 = item2.next();
    scan3 = item3.next();
    if (scan1.contains(salami) && scan2.contains(capicola) && scan3.contains(cheese)){
        System.out.println("Great job!");
        menuItem =+ 1;
        points++;
        System.out.println(points);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Lets try that again!");     
        menuItem = 4;
    }
case 5:
    System.out.println("What items are on the Slim 6 from the bread up");
    scan1 = item1.next();
    scan2 = item2.next();
    scan3 = item3.next();
    if (scan1.contains(cheese) && scan2.contains(cheese)){
        System.out.println("Great job!");
        menuItem =+ 1;
        points++;
        System.out.println(points);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Lets try that again!"); 
        menuItem = 5;
    }
    break;
case 6:
    System.out.println("What items are on the #1 Pepe from the bread up");
    break;
case 7:
    System.out.println("What items are on the #2 Big John from the bread up");
    break;
case 8:
    System.out.println("What items are on the #3 Totally Tuna from the bread up");
    break;
case 9:
    System.out.println("What items are on the #4 Turkey Tom from the bread up");
    break;
case 10:
    System.out.println("What items are on the #5 Vito from the bread up");
    break;
case 11:
    System.out.println("What items are on the #6 Veggie from the bread up");
    break;
case 12:
    System.out.println("What items are on the JJBLT from the bread up");
    break;  
case 13:
    System.out.println("What items are on the #7 Smoked Ham Club from the bread up");
    break;  
case 14:
    System.out.println("What items are on the #8 Billy Club from the bread up");
    break;  
case 15:
    System.out.println("What items are on the #9 Italian Club from the bread up");
    break;  
case 16:
    System.out.println("What items are on the #10 Hunters Club from the bread up");
    break;  
case 17:
    System.out.println("What items are on the #11 Country Club from the bread up");
    break;  
case 18:
    System.out.println("What items are on the #12 Beach Club from the bread up");
    break;  
case 19:
    System.out.println("What items are on the #13 Veggie Club from the bread up");
    break;  
case 20:
    System.out.println("What items are on the #14 Bootlegger Club from the bread up");
    break;  
case 21:
    System.out.println("What items are on the #15 Club Tuna from the bread up");
    break;  
case 22:
    System.out.println("What items are on the #16 Club Lulu from the bread up");
    break;  
case 23:
    System.out.println("What items are on the #17 Ultimate Porker from the bread up");
    break;  
case 24:
    System.out.println("What items are on the Gargantuan from the bread up");
    break;  
}

return;


}while(points < 24);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated greatly!

Thanks,

Quinten

Comment: Add a `break` statement to the end of each case clause. Read up on `switch` in Java. Also, you are doing countless wrong things. I'd recommend finding an online tutorial to get you started. Creating dozens of Scanner instances is not the way to read data

Comment: You only need one `Scanner` to point at `System.in`. Also don't need variables for every string value if you aren't going to change them or use a shorter name. Just use the string literals in your code.

Comment: You're also using `=+` instead of `+=`. There's a huge difference. One assigns a positive number, the other increments the variable by a number.

Comment: Use only one scanner!!

Comment: Place a while loop and use a boolean around each Q%A, if they get it right the loop control variable will become false and therefore proceed to the next question

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in your `menuItem =+ 1;` statements.  `=+` isn't actually a supported java operator. The actual code is supposed to be

```
menuItem += 1;
```

This difference might seem minor, but your code is essentially doing:

```
menuItem = +1;
```

where `+1` might equal 2? I'm not sure.  But I don't think it's doing what you think it's doing.  I would lean towards removing all of these statements anyway, as you don't need to change `menuItem` when they answer incorrectly.  If you leave it the same, the loop will continue with the same menuItem, which it seems is what you want.  Only increment on successful answers.

Another thing to note is that String.Contains is case-sensitive, and you seem to be inconsistent with your menu item declarations.  You could try this instead:

```
scan1.EqualsIgnoreCase(tuna);
```

Also, you don't need a new `Scanner()` for every question.  You can reuse scanners for multiple inputs, as you do many times with `item1`.

So you could clean up your code by replacing:

```
scan1 = item1.next();
scan2 = item2.next();
scan3 = item3.next();
```

with

```
string salamiTest = testScanner.next();
string capicolaTest = testScanner.next();
string cheeseTest = testScanner.next();

if (salamiTest.EqualsIgnoreCase(salami) /* && otherTests */) {
    points++;
    menuItem++;
}
// else { they are wrong, don't increment menuItem }
```